# 敵の数に応じて Slider の値を減少処理方法

Tags: c#, unity2d

**やりたいこと**
Slider　の値を敵モンスターの数に応じて、少しずつ減らしたいです。

画面上に敵モンスターがいるとします。
この敵モンスターが画面上にいると、
時間とともに（たとえば１秒ごとに）、
モンスターの数に応じて
Sliderの値がどんどん減少していく、という処理をしたいです。

**発生している問題**
１体のモンスターが画面上にいる場合は、解決できました。
しかし、同じモンスターが画面に複数いる場合にも、
Slider の値が１体分しか減りません。

たとえば、３体いるなら、３体分減少させたいです。
そして、
１体倒して２体に減ったら、２体分、というように変化させたいです。

**該当のソースコード**
敵モンスター側のコードが以下になります。

```
float Damage = 1.0f;
float timeLeft;

……

void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (timeLeft <= 0.0)
    {
        timeLeft = 1.0f;
        stressSliderManager.Minus(Damage);
    }
```

次に、スライダー側（空のGameObjectに付与しているスクリプト）が以下です。

```
public void Minus(float Damage)
{
    HPnow -= Damage;
    MySlider.value = HPnow;
}
```

**試したこと**
まずは敵モンスターをプレハブとして、同じものを３体配置。
しかし、上記の `Damage = 1.0f` にある通り、１秒に１ずつしか減りませんでした。

次に、メソッドの名前が同じのを使ってるからいけないのかも、と考え、
モンスターは同じでも、名前を変えたメソッドを用意して書き換えました。
（Minus2nd といったようにです。）
やはり、中身が同じだからなのか（？）１ずつしか減りません。

３体の場合、１秒に３減らしていくにはどのように記述すればよいでしょうか。
ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 単純に戦闘範囲に居る敵の数を変数に入れておいて、`Minus()`を呼び出す際に`Damage`に掛ければ良いのでは？ こちらの記事は敵に与えるダメージをブーストする処理のようですが類似と思われます。[Btttonを押した後５秒間UIのスライダーの減少量を２倍にしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/130614)

Comment: ちなみにこちらで先に質問されてますね。[【Unity】敵の数に応じてのSliderの値減少処理](https://teratail.com/questions/285174)

Comment: その前に「３体いるなら、３体分減少させたい」対象は何でしょう？ その対象オブジェクトのスクリプトに処理を組み込まないと意味が無いのでは？

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。　私のミスで、書いてなかったことがあるのですが、敵の種類によって減らす値は異なります。そのため、お答えいただいたことをもとに、考えてみたのですが、敵の種類をわけてそれぞれ別の変数に入れるかなにかして、その数と減らす値をかけて、Damageに足していくみたいにしてみようと思いました。減少させたい対象は、体力のゲージ（Slider）です。うまくお伝えできてるかわかりませんが、ひとまず頂いたヒントをもとにやってみようと思っています。